# $pristine $dirty properties aren't updating within my custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently in the middle of learning AngularJS and was attempting to create a custom directive for input fields on a form. The directive would have dynamic validation rules based on the rules you gave it. The issue I'm having though is that the formController's and ngMOdelController's $dirty & $pristine properties don't change even after interacting with the field. I have a plunk setup to illustrate my problem here: http://plnkr.co/edit/JahbBHZm7sH8t6qWxOBY

Here's the snippet:

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$timeout', '$compile', function($timeout, $compile) { 
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: ['?^form', '?ngModel'],
      templateUrl: 'field-template.html',
      scope: {
        value: '=ngModel',
        fieldName: '@',
        validation: '@',
        labelText: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, controllers) {
        var $element = $(element);
        scope.form = controllers[0];
        scope.model = controllers[1];

        $timeout(function() {
          if (!scope.validation) return;
          var validation = scope.$eval(scope.validation);

          for (var key in validation) {
            $element.find('#' + scope.fieldName).attr(key, validation[key]);
          }

          $compile($element.contents())(scope);
        });

      }
    };
  }]);
```

Comment: Compiling something that was already compiled is an anti-pattern and could yield to undesired results. Also, instead of passing the validation rules as attributes I suggest you define an API for your component. Example: my-directive-min-length="3" to define the minimum length. That way you avoid recompiling the element.

Comment: I had to recompile the element contents because markup is being loaded asynchronously via templateUrl. I read a little about it here: https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/service/$compile#post-linking-function

Comment: Your post-linking function will not get executed until the template is downloaded. The link you posted refers to accessing child elements that asynchronous loading template.

Comment: when i try to append attributes outside of the $timeout function, they don't appear once the view has loaded. I had to append attributes within the $timeout function as it executes the code within in once the DOM has fully loaded. my next problem was that the attributes weren't being registered by angular so none of the validation was working which is why i re-compiled after.

Comment: The reason because the attributes don't get appended to the element has nothing to do with the templateUrl but rather with the fact that you try to find an element by id but the {{ }} on the input id attribute haven't run as they run after the linking function. As I said before, I suggest you create an interface to your component and don't apply the attributes via jquery to your input bur rather assign the attribute value to a property in the scope. That is the angular way.